# Como compartilhar uma imagem como previa do site com o navigator share

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando colocar uma prévia do site no compartilhamento do link de forma nativa através do JavaScript usando o navigator.share(). Mais não consigo fazer isso

```
<script>function share(){
if (navigator.share !== undefined) {
    navigator.share({
       title:'compre agora com 15% de desconto',
       text:'compre agora somente no nosso site',
        url:'https://meusite',
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
}}</script>
```

Esse é o código, ele funciona compartilhando o link o título e o texto. Alguém sabe como eu conseguia compartilhar uma imagem junto a essas informações?

Answer (score 1):

O [**`navigator.share`**](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_navigator_share) não tem imagem, no máximo o que você pode fazer (que é bem limitado ainda) é enviar arquivos.

Se observar bem, adicionando um link copiado manualmente em postagens de *redes sociais* (Facebook, VK, etc), *mensageiros* (Telegram, WhatsApp, etc) vai notar que eles próprios detectam a(s) imagem(s) de pré-visualização, alguns suportam mais de uma imagem, isso é feito pelos próprias *redes sociais*, *mensageiros* e outros tipos de programa (com suporte), de forma independente, eles é quem acessam a página de destino do link e tentam determinar o conteúdo através de *web scraping*, isso geralmente é feito com o apoio das [META-tags OpenGraph](https://ogp.me/) vindas da página de destino (explico melhor isso no final).

Como disse no começo, o envio de arquivos via `navigator.share` é **bastante limitado**, isso porque o [**`navigator.canShare()`**](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_navigator_canshare) e o `files:` tem suporte *parcial no macOS em navegadores baseados em Chromium* (Edge, Chrome, Opera, etc), o `files:` também não é suportado pelo **Firefox Android**, os únicos navegadores com suporte "completo" são:

## Suporte para `navigator.canShare()`

| Safari MacOS | Chrome Android | Firefox Android | Safari iOS | Samsung Internet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 75 | 96 | 15 | 11 |

## Suporte para o parâmetro `data.files`

| Safari MacOS | Chrome Android | Safari iOS | Samsung Internet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 76 | 15 | 11 |

Um exemplo de uso do `navigator.share` + `data.files`:

```
const arquivos = [];

// pode usar fetch() ou um <canvas>+drawImage para "converter" uma imagem existente (use o arraybuffer)
arquivos.push(new File([arraybuffer], 'foto.jpg', { type: 'image/jpeg' }));

// Testa se os arquivos enviados são suportados
if (navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare({ files: arquivos })) {
    navigator.share({
        files: arquivos,
        title: 'Foo bar baz',
        text: 'Foo bar baz etc',
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Compartilhado com sucesso');
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Sharing failed', error)
    });
} else {
    console.error('Seu navegador não suporta navigator.share');
}
```

No exemplo acima o `arraybuffer` deve ser uma variável, que pode ter sido obtida de um `<canvas>` ou com `fetch()` (supondo que sua intenção seja compartilhar uma imagem estática existente no servidor).

Isso é o máximo (e bem limitado) que conseguirá com `navigator.share` e como já dito, **isso não é um "preview"**.

---

### Resolvendo a pré-visualização

Como já explicado, quem gera a pré-visualização são os aplicativos, programas, rede sociais, etc, aonde o usuário irá postar o link, através do processo de *web scraping* e para facilitar esse trabalho dos *"clientes"* (mensageiros, redes sociais, etc) buscarem esses dados, foram desenvolvidas as [**META-tags OpenGraph**](https://ogp.me/), então sem o link compartilhado tiver em sua página uma estrutura semelhante a isso:

```
<head>
<title>Titulo da página</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Titulo da página" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://url completa da página (canonical)" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://seusite/images/preview.jpg" />
...
</head>
```

Os *"clientes"* (mensageiros, redes sociais, etc) irão acessar a página do link e pegarão os valores dessas META-tags para gerar o *preview* (não só da imagem, mas de outros detalhes que forem pertinentes).

Em resumo, quem gera essas pré-visualizações, na hora de compartilhar, geralmente são as META-tags OpenGraph e na ausência delas um *"cliente"* poderá tentar contornar (buscando outras imagens) ou ignorar a pré-visualização, isso depende do *"cliente"*, alguns irão tentar compensar buscando conteúdo no corpo da página, já outros não.

É importante notar que dependendo se o site estiver **fora dor**, **lento** ou **oscilando**, os *"clientes"* podem ignorar essa parte de baixar os dados do OpenGraph, pois problemas de conectividade não podem interferir na entrega de mensagens, o *preview* é mais uma "perfumaria".

Comment: Guilherme, estou tentando criar um compartilhamento para os produtos do meu site. Queria fazer assim como o mercado livre faz, onde ao compartilhar o produto é enviado também a imagem dele. Para fazer algo semelhante seria melhor fazer qual?

Comment: @Gabriel leu a parte da resposta que eu falei sobre o OpenGraph? Pois implemente isso em seu site, o op:image pode ser adicionado mais de uma vez, ou seja, você pode ter várias imagens com `<meta property="og:image" content="..." />`. Como eu disse, não é exatamente o MercadoLivre que envia a imagem, é o cliente (whatsapp, telegra, facebook, etc) que buscam pela URL informada se existe o OpenGraph dentro do seu site.

Comment: Entendi Irei implementar agora, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @Gabriel editei a resposta, para melhor entendimento do processo dos aplicativos, programas, redes sociais, etc, para gerar as *pré-visualizações* de links. Em resumo, é um processo de *web scraping* com o auxilio do OpenGraph.